# selenium click works but does not get the element on the next window

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Angularjs ui-routes and I have a link as follows.

```
<a ui-sref="devs" href="#/devs"> Devs</a>
```

My code is as follows

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('selenium-tests/chromedriver')

driver.get("http://localhost")

menu = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Devs')

menu.click()

print (driver.current_url)

driver.close()
```

After the click the url should be http://localhost/#/dev and I can see the window  changing in the browser as well however when I print it's still http://localhost,

I have tried window handles but it does not work, Any help will be  apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

*Give it time and [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html) for the URL to change.*

For instance, you may wait for the page title to be equal to "Devs" (assuming this is the case):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ...

menu.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.title_is("Devs"))

print(driver.current_url)
```

Or, wait for the URL to be equal the desired one:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.current_url == "http://localhost/#/dev")
```

---

Or, you may try *increasing the page load time*:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
```

---

In order to debug the problem, print out the current urls that are checked during the wait:

```
def wait_for_url(driver):
    print(driver.current_url)
    return driver.current_url == "http://localhost/#/dev"

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(wait_for_url)
```

Comment: I tried with timeout 60 seconds and it gave me a timeout exception  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.current_url == "http://scaffold/#/dev")

Comment: @LeoG I think the problem is in the url you are checking - instead of `scaffold/#/dev` it should be a complete url used.

Comment: I used the full url, the comment removes the http part

Comment: @LeoG updated the answer and included on how to debug the problem. Try it out.

Comment: thx, but it continues to print http://localhost/ which is very strange coz the click moves to the next page

Comment: @LeoG btw, could you please try that in Firefox? Thanks.

Comment: I have changed the driver to Phamtomjs, but still no luck, will try firefox

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `ui-sref` and `href` together or you may run into some strange issues like what you are experiencing now. Since you are using ui-router, you should not need to use the `href` tag unless you are linking to an external site or going to a page different than your angular app.

Comment: I havn't that's what is displayed when I do an inspect element